# Unsupported element in unpacked struct datatype in formal argument

Tags: c, system-verilog, system-verilog-dpi

I'm having trouble passing a structure object from SV to C through SV-C DPI.

The code:

SV side:

```
/*svFile.sv*/
typedef struct {
    int a; 
    int b;  
} struct_sv;
import "DPI-C" function void reciever(input struct_sv a);
```

and on the C side

```
/*cFile.c*/
void reciever(const struct_sv *x){
    printf("%d %d", x->a, x->b);
}
```

But when I compile and run, I get the following error:

```
ncvlog: *E,UNUSAG unsupported element in unpacked struct datatype in formal argument.
```

Comment: What is `struct_c`?

Comment: My bad it's struct_sv. Edit made.

Comment: And this is exactly the struct typedef that gives that error?

Comment: Did you include `#include "svdpi.h"` and `#include "svdpi_src.h"` in your C file? They are necessary for data type mapping purposes.

Comment: I included "svdpi.h". Didn't include "svdpi_src.h" since the structures contain int only.

Comment: Then you're right. I found [this](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/array-real-numbers-inside-structure-and-passing-it-dpi-c-call-not-possible) which is actually your question. There is also an answer: `An unsupported feature usually means it is legal, but the tool is not supporting it yet. [...] Contact your vendor for tool related issues.`. So which tool you're using? Is there maybe an update?

Comment: `struct_sv` needs to be defined on the C and SV side. Currently you are missing the C side, therefore it will not know what struct_sv is.

Comment: @Greg: I don't think he missed it because then he could **not** compile the C code. But he can as he run it and get the error.

Comment: You can do "read" inside the struct_sv if you include the vpi header and use vpi functions to look inside a SV struct.   But VPI is a can of worm on its own.  I did it once before, it is do-able, but I don't recommend mixing DPI and VPI.  It defeats the point of using DPI in the first place.

Comment: Looked at your ncvlog error, I've also tried NC's irun. You have to also declare C's struct type in C source code. I ran `ncverilog -sv svFile.sv cFile.c` and the simulator (15.1) can work without problems. Please upgrade or change your SV simulator.